# How to force override an existing type in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik

I am using the Formik, a React form library and creating my own custom fields. I'm relying on Formik's generic `Schema` type which represents their `values` object, which contains all the values for all the fields in the form.

The custom component is checkboxgroup component that takes FormikProps

```js
type FormikProps<Schema> = {
  ...
  values: Schema
}

type Groceries = Array<{
  id: string;
  value: string;
}>

type Schema = {
  ...
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  groceries: Groceries
}

type Props<Schema> = {
  ...
  name: keyof Schema & string;
} & FormikProps<Schema, unknown>

type State = {
  isBananaSelectedInGroceries: boolean;
}

const getInitialState = (props: Props) => {
  const groceries = props.values["groceries"];

  // Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Schema[keyof Schema & string]'.ts(2339)
  const values = groceries.map(({ value }) => value);
  ...
}

export class CheckboxGroup<Schema> extends React.Component<
  Props<Schema>,
  State
> {
  state = getInitialState(this.props);
  ...
}
```

In `getInitialState`, typescript is complaining that `groceries` is not an array. So in an attempt to force override the type, I tried this:

```js
  // Type 'Schema[keyof Schema & string]' is not assignable to type 'Groceries'.
  //     Type 'Schema[string]' is not assignable to type '{ id: string; value: string; }[]'.ts(2322)
  const groceries: Groceries = props.values["groceries"];
  const values = groceries.map(({ value }) => value);
```

I can typecast it this way, then the error goes away - but this is obviously not ideal:

```
  const groceries: Groceries = (props.values["groceries"] as unknown) as Groceries;
  const values = groceries.map(({ value }) => value);
```

1. What's going on here? Why isn't Typescript inferring that `values["groceries"]` is an `Array`?
2. What would be the ideal way to make Typescript happy here?

Comment: Consider providing a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) so that people who want to help can demonstrate the issue for themselves.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You had a few errors in your typescript declarations. After fixing them everything works as expected: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=27&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9gJwLYEsDWAFBcwGcA8AygMYAWESAhgHxQC8UA3gLABQUUAbpQDYCuEXAC4oJclTYBfNm1CQoAcWzEICFIPpQAgggSUQ+FuygoAJiNzA1AOwDmAbjYdu-CBaso7j1pOozWctBiFJSaRhwAZigIlgBylEhuUJY2Dk5QPJRxCUkpnmnGtsqq6sKKxWqCUv6BUFg4uGHp1jkiaBAgcBGiZCFQAGTJHl5SA7CIqJjYeES9VH6ssuBBwJTA0AzhJrgAQpQtLYQQPBDE66YAktZKcCqVZQBGcHAn+97Si6zEcNaWULYQYBXFDAFC8QirdaaAAUYGmZXqeAAlPRaFtvr9gP8KqVNHCGgA6FwCXAAbQAREVbiVBOSALreDgYv7EjQMKl3UoEqhgaHQxhcXgCKCSFF0WispHvIA)

The main issue was `const getInitialState = (props: Props)` because `Props` was a generic type (but it didn't need to be, at least in the current implementation).

Generally you should only use generics if you need to change them dynamically (use T for example, not an exact type because that might create confusion).

```
type FormikProps = {
  values: Schema
}

type Groceries = Array<{
  id: string;
  value: string;
}>

type Schema = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  groceries: Groceries
}

type Props = {
  name: keyof Schema & string;
} & FormikProps

type State = {
  isBananaSelectedInGroceries: boolean;
}

const getInitialState = (props: Props) => {
  const groceries = props.values["groceries"];
  const values = groceries.map(({ value }) => value);
}
```